# запись с кэша данных на HDD

Tags: linux

Имеется docker контейнер с работающим RabbitMQ, хостимся мы на AWS и хотелось бы увеличить объем дискового пространства, так вот хотелось бы узнать перед остановкой контейнера какая комманда в linux позволяет записать данные с кэша на диск? т.е в Linux насколько я помню данные не сразу попадают на HDD, сначала они попадают в "кэш" и в определенное время или при определенной загрузки, данные записываются на диск, так вот какой командой можно произвести сие действие?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна команда...

```
sync
```

> The sync utility can be called to ensure that all disk writes have been completed before the processor is halted.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!

Comment: Галочка слева от ответа - лучшее спасибо

Comment: увы, но не хватает репутации